# Return a non-future from an async function

Tags: dart

I have a simple function that retrieves some `UserData` from our backend if its cache has expired. The commented return below created some odd behaviours. On a whim, I wrapped my `_cache` value in a `Future` and voila, though I'm perplexed why. I had assumed that Dart would wrap my return in a `Future`, but clearly there's something fundamental I do not understand. Can someone explain to me the difference between the two return values from within an `async` function?

```
UserData _cache;

Future<UserData> getUserData() async {
  if (isCacheStale) {
    _cache = await _endpoint.getUserData();
  }

  return Future(() => _cache);  // <- Works
  // return _cache;             // <- Does not work
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @KirillBubochkin I didn't get a compile error or runtime error. Our app was navigating to the wrong page, which was weird. I was tracking down the cause when I wrapped the return value in the Future and the behaviour changed. I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: Returning a `Future` from an `async` function is implicitly transformed into `return await theFuture;`, so perhaps your application is sensitive to the additional `await`.

Comment: @jamesdlin. I was suspicious that was the reason. Thanks very much for the confirmation!

Comment: @jamesdlin nice!! I was having similar doubt on returning Future<T> from async function. Can you kindly point to documentation that supports this? It is quite unintuitive behavior :(

Comment: @barley It's probably in the Dart language spec, but that's not written in plain English and is hard to understand.  There is a messy web of GitHub issues about it (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/791, https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39204, https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44395).  That it's unintuitive is a reason why disallowing `return someFuture` from an `async` function is being considered (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/870).

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for the links!! Hmm, sounds like always `await` explicitly for returning `Future` is a safe convention at this moment 